# Запуск Java приложений без консоли!

Tags: java

Начал изучать Java, до этого был опыт в Python. В Python я мог написать код сохранить в файл с расширением .py и просто запускать его. 
В Java же так не получается, нужно только использовать cmd или терминал в Linux для запуска файлов с кодом. 
Но и запуск просто файла, не достаточно, хочется например, написать какое-то пусть пока даже консольное приложение и передать кому-то ради интереса, но тупо будет просить человека запускать его через консоль. 
Как можно запаковать файлы например в .exe ?

Comment: пользуйтесь например intellij idea

Comment: в java нет exe файлов, вместо них используется jar, для того, что бы собрать jar можно воспользоваться любой IDE. Можно конечно и через консоль собрать jar, но врятле это понадобиться, вот тут пример https://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще, если есть такое желание упаковывать java программу в exe, надо задуматься, тот ли язык вы выбрали?

Но если отвечать на ваш вопрос, то можно:

1. Собрать exe с помощью:

   - http://www.excelsior-usa.com/resources.html
   - http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/
2. Запаковать программу в jar (имплементировав логику консольного прерывания, например, через Scanner, чтобы программа после исполнения не закрылась)
3. Запаковать программу в jar и написать .bat файл примерно со следукщим кодом: 
   java -jar youApp.jar
   pause

Comment: Excelsior вообще мощную штуку делает - компилятор Java. )