# Как запустить .java программу через .bat так, чтобы командная строка не отображалась?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Код запуска программы "java Main.java"

Или может есть другие более удобные способы запустить .java программу, без .bat?

Comment: `bat`  по-моему, всегда при запуске отображает командную строку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск Java приложений без консоли!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521545/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)